# Terminate process in qt. WaitForSingleObject is never succeed

Tags: c++, qt, winapi, process

I'm using QT for developing. I'm using `QProcess::startDetached` to launch a process. At some point I need to terminate it. As I understood I need platform-specific code for this. I'm not familiar with windows programming but I found that I need to use `TerminateProcess` to terminate a process. And examples I found look like this:

```
if(WaitForSingleObject(processHandle, INFINITE) == WAIT_OBJECT_0)
{
     TerminateProcess(processHandle, 0);
}
```

In my case `WaitForSingleObject` never ends. If I use some timeout, this function return after timeout with fail result. I'm not 100% sure how `WaitForSingleObject` works and will be grateful if someone explain. And  most of all I interested to know why it doesn't work with QT application.

I tried to terminate a separate process and also the main process itself, i.e. call this function in the main.

Comment: `WaitForSingleObject` on a process handle waits for that process to exit. Why would you then call `TerminateProcess` on it? It has already exited!

Comment: @Dark Falcon I need to terminate it by myself. And how do you know that it waits process to exit? MSDN says nothing about this.

Comment: `When a process terminates, the state of the process object becomes signaled`: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686722%28v=vs.85%29.aspx `WaitForSingleObject` waits for the object to become signaled. Microsoft could afford to improve their documentation by listing this info in the WaitForSingleObject page.

Comment: @Dark Falcon Ok, I got this, thank you. But does process signals **only** when it terminates? Or it can signal by some other reason?

Comment: Yes, only when it terminates/exits. Waiting on a process handle would be pretty useless if it signaled some other time as well. The entire point of waiting on a process handle is to wait for the process to exit.

Comment: In this kind of example, you would use `TerminateProcess()` if `WaitForSingleObject()` times out or errors, thus you can force the process to terminate since you don't know when it will actually terminate. You don't use `TerminateProcess()` when the process terminates normally (which is what `WAIT_OBJECT_0` indicates). And really, you should not be using `TerminateProcess()` anyway, except as a **last resort** since it is brute force immediate termination. There are better ways to use Inter-Process Communication mechanisms to signal the process to terminate itself gracefully when needed.